# ¿Por qué mi texto se modifica? y ¿Cómo evito que se modifique?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una pagina para cargar contenido desde una base de datos la cosa es que la información para saber que contenido mostrar la paso a través de la URL Ejemplo:

[www.MiDominioWeb.com/Articulo?¿Un-México-de-percepciones-o-realidades](http://www.MiDominioWeb.com/Articulo?%C2%BFUn-M%C3%A9xico-de-percepciones-o-realidades)?
y para obtener el contenido solo elimino el texto que esta antes del signo de interrogación pero es justo aquí cuando ocurre un error ya que el texto "Especial" como Signos de interrogación y acentos se modifica y no me permite saber cual es el contenido a mostrar, les mostrare el código que tengo junto con un ejemplo de que es lo que sucede.

```
//URL Completa: www.MidominioWeb.com/Articulo?¿Un-México-de-percepciones-o-realidades?

let URLArticle;

URLArticle = window.location.href;

PostTitleToLoad = URLArticle.replace("www.MidominioWeb.com/Articulo?", "");

PageTitle = PostTitleToLoad.replace("-", " ");

document.title = PageTitle;

console.log(URLArticle);
console.log(PostTitleToLoad);
console.log(PageTitle);

Consola:

 https://www.MidominioWeb.com/Articulo?%C2%BFUn-M%C3%A9xico-de-percepciones-o-realidades?


%C2%BFUn-M%C3%A9xico-de-percepciones-o-realidades?

%C2%BFUn M%C3%A9xico-de-percepciones-o-realidades?
```

Como pueden ver el Signo de Interrogación ¿ se cambio a %C2%BF y los acentos a %C3%A9 ¿Así que mi pregunta es como puedo evitar que suceda esto?

Comment: Y por qué ibas a querer evitar que suceda eso?? Eso es enconding de urls, y sirve para evitar usar caracteres raros en las url como son los acentos y los símbolos de interrogación que no existen en otros idiomas y no son "*seguros*" para mostrarse/usarse en programas. Los navegadores hacen la conversión automaticamente para que las URL sean seguras.  Te dejo un enlace a la documentación de W3Schools donde se habla del [percent enconding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP#:~:text=Since%20URLs%20often%20contain%20characters,(%2B)%20sign%20or%20with%20%20.) o URL Encoding

Comment: Entonces ¿Lo mejor es eliminar signos de Interrogación y acentos? ¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: No necesitas eliminarlos, no hacen daño... pero si quieres que las url sean mas "vistosas" y fáciles de escribir para los usuarios... simplemente ***NO*** uses acentos ni símbolos raros en tus URL. Por cierto, sí se puede modificar el servidor web para que acepte esos símbolos en las URL (Tal como se muestran por ejemplo aquí en SO), pero eso dependerá de qué servidor web estás usando, y no tiene nada que ver con javascript/html

Comment: 1) Como identificador del artículo deberías usar un código; no quieres que si cambias el título de tu artículo todos los enlaces que haya a éste queden obsoletos. 2) Lo que se suele hacer es poner en la URL el código y luego añadir detrás el texto descriptivo, lo que hace el servidor es que se fija solo en el código e ignora todo el texto (p.ej. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418839/elperroderoquenotienerabo). 3) Busca por "URL beautifiers" (embellecedor de URLs) para ejemplos y librerías que se encargan de esto.